# error while using mathjax api offline

Tags: html, mathjax

I have downloaded mathjax file to my system, i want to use that api in my application, 
my system will rarely connected to internet 
while using api fonts/image are not displaying it is loading blank space. 
i am using IE 8 , IIS and windows 7

Thanks

Comment: How are you referencing the mathjax libraries in your page?

Comment: This sounds like a good candidate for an [offline app](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html), which unfortunately isn't supported by IE8. If you're using Windows 7, could you upgrade to IE10, or possibly Chrome or FF?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to diagnose your problem.  You should include a sample page so that we can see how you are loading and calling MathJax.

Comment: it works in FF with image fonts ,
after installing fonts in client machine it is working perfect in all browser with math fonts  , this is good for now